How to measure touch pressure in flutter
I need to measure how much force does the user put on the screen (pressure when touch).
in GestureDetector's ForcePress callbacks provide a details (ForcePressDetails) object which contains pressure value, but it's always returns 1 when user press. the doc says it return either 0 or 1.
GestureDetector(
onForcePressStart: (details){
                print(details.pressure);// always print 1
              },
)

So, this's not an actual pressure measurement, is there any workaround ideas!

it means that there is no sensor for pressure on your device - so it always shows the max pressure (the docs say: '''A value of 0.0 is no pressure, and 1.0 is maximum pressure.''')

So to find out, the OP needs to set a validation to check if his/her device has pressure sensor.

@pskink, got it ,thank you.

sure, your welcome
